# How to define While(boolean) loop in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, while-loop, undefined

I cannot get the While loop to run. The error message is as follows:

```
Thread [main] (Suspended (The method While(boolean) is undefined for the type While_loop_App))  
    While_loop_App.main(String[]) line: 11
```

What must I do?

Comment: put your code in the question please.

Answer (score 2):

the method syntax should be:  `while(boolValue)`
where `boolValue` is the boolean you are passing in the loop.
please note that `while` is all lowercase. Ideally your eclipse should give you a error there itself while typing the code.

Answer (score 1):

Use `while` (with lowercase `w`) instead of `While`.